# Can 66% DC 5V PWM signal damage 3V rated components

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, maximum-ratings

Hopefully a simple question here, but I have a 3V motor that I was hoping to control with a 5V PWM, which got me to thinking more about how PWM averages out a signal to give a lower voltage, essentially. My specific question is this:

Even though, say, a 50% duty cycle 5V PWM signal looks like devices to be 2.5V, can that 5V signal still damage motors, LEDs, etc since its max amplitude is still 5V and could be out of the operating range of, say, 3.3V powered motors? Or perhaps due to how the power is utilized by such devices, the motors cannot tell if the source is a 100% DC 3.3V or a 66% DC 5V signal? I would imagine damage could occur, but I have not found confirmation yet and am curious if we need to worry about this sort of things when powering motors.

Comment: This is not answerable for "components" in general.  For a motor, with suitable duty cycle it typically works, for small low voltage motors it's pretty typical.  Do pay attention though to things like current rating, and avoid horribly lossy *darlington* bridges for your PWM!

Comment: Maybe a thought experiment: at what frequency? 0.0001Hz? :P

Comment: @WesleyLee it's not clear that the motor in question would actually be damaged by *permanent* connection to a 5v supply.  Or for that matter how long it's going to last on a 3v one.  And then one has to consider the mechanical load...

Comment: @ChrisStratton - yes of course, my point is just that OPs question leaves a lot of room for interpretation (also like you said this is unanswerable for "components")

Comment: Motor will be fine, LEDs, MCUs etc not so much.

Comment: Very informative. In the case of this motor, it will definitely be damaged by excessive voltage: manufacturer says 1000 hours of operation at 3V, 72 hours at 5V. I guess with motors it is important to check with manufacturer for the more specific answer of how much, if any, real damage could occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Even though, say, a 50% duty cycle 5V PWM signal looks like devices to
> be 2.5V, can that 5V signal still damage motors, LEDs, etc since its
> max amplitude is still 5V

Yes. PWM applies full voltage to the device for a time, then removes it for a time. Even if the *average* voltage is fine, the device's ratings may be exceeded during the PWM 'on' time. It might be damaged even by short spikes of over-voltage - either due to insulation breakdown, excessive current draw through critical areas ('hot spots') or misoperation (eg. [latch-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latch-up)). It might also be damaged by high peak temperature, or thermal stress as it heats up and cools down.

LEDs draw exponentially increasing current once a threshold is reached, so a typical White LED with nominal 3.0 V drop draws very little current at 2.5 V but many times its rating at 5 V. LED voltage drop also varies with temperature and between individual units, so some form of current stabilization is always required. If a resistor is used then it must be tailored to match the *peak* voltage applied.

Motors tend to smooth out current variations due to inductance of the windings, but if the PWM frequency is low relative to the [LR time constant](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/inductor/lr-circuits.html) then the current variation will be large, causing vibration and increased rms current which will heat it up more. The minimum PWM frequency to get acceptably low current ripple depends on the motor's construction. Iron-cored motors usually only need about 3 kHz, but coreless motors may need 30 kHz or higher.

Another thing to bear in mind is that as PWM ratio is lowered the ratio of motor current to power supply current increases, so you may measure the supply current and think the motor is within its ratings when in fact it is overloaded. At 50% PWM the motor will be passing double the power supply current.

High peak voltage also increases commutator arcing and can break down insulation, but this is unlikely to be a problem in a 3 V brushed DC motor running from 5 V. The main reason for it being rated at 3 V is probably excessive brush bounce and arcing at higher rpm.

Answer (score 2):

DC motors is a coil, when voltage connected the current rises linearly until the coil saturates. You avoid saturation by increasing the PWM frequency. With the right frequency you can drive the motor with any PWM voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Semiconductors don't respond well to even brief over-voltage
but it gets worse.

5V at 50% PWM is 3.5V RMS (not 2.5V)

so it will damage most things that can only handle 3V

Expect it to shorten the life of your 2.5V motor while only driving the motor at the 2.5V speed.

5V at 66% PWM is 4V RMS  even worse.